# Attribute field issue when editing layer properties (ArcGIS)

Tags: attributes, field, arcgis, esri

I am working with an XY dataset imported to Arc from a csv file. The data appears to be importing correctly, and all of data is displaying properly, and is shown in the attribute table.

However when I try to edit the layer properties using a graduated color analysis in the symbology, one of the relevant attribute fields is not displaying. The imported data has proper column headings naming each column, and they appear exactly as they should in the attribute table. Looking at the "Fields" tab in the layer properties, all attribute fields are present, and selected to appear, including the one that does NOT appear in the drop down menu when I try to do a graduated color analysis.

Adding to my frustration is the fact that the field I am interested in was appearing and I was able to work with it yesterday. It disappeared when I exported the data as a shapefile. I have imported two different csv files as layers, and when I import the other csv the relevant field appears as expected, including after the shapefile export. It simply eludes me for this one csv file. I have tried re downloading the data (originally a txt file) and then importing to Excel, and saving as a csv. But the problem persists. Each time I import this data the needed field does not appear in the drop down menu.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Comment: Please use the "answer yourself" function (bottom of the page) and put your solution into the answer there to finish this question.

Comment: I've noticed it's important the relevant attribute field as a string (non-numeric) now. The data should be a double, as it is comprised entirely of numbers and a column heading. The other fields are all importing as doubles, but this one is a string for some reason.

Comment: @MaxLeske

I got ahead of myself and thought it was resolved, but not quite. 

Besides, as a new user I am unable to "answer myself" for 8 hours.